# PolygonShape is not updated by its body

Tags: c#, .net, xna-4.0, farseer

I'm trying to define a polygon to be updated by a body bounded by a physical world. Here it goes my attempt:

```
public Body _body;
public Shape _shape;
_primitiveBatch = new PrimitiveBatch(_game.GraphicsDevice);
_shape = new PolygonShape(_vertices, 1);
Vector2 _position = FarseerPolygon.getCenter(((PolygonShape)_shape).Vertices);
_body = new Body(_world);
_body.Position = _position;
_body.CreateFixture(_shape);
_body.BodyType = BodyType.Dynamic;
_body.Restitution = 0.9f;
_body.Friction = 1f;
```

The body changes its position but not the shape. Body.CreatePolygon also doesn't work. Any help would really be appreciated because I'm stucked in here... Thank you,

Comment: im @ work so I cannot give you any code examples, I would have a look at using the bodyfactory. It should do a whole bunch of the work for you.

Comment: It is solved, Jastill. Thank you very much for your concern :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The polygon is not supposed to change position. It's a performance thing. The `Fixture` and its `Shape` are designed to exist in "Model Space" (close to (0,0)) and not change. Then the `Body` defines the transform to place that shape in "World Space".

To get the individual points of a polygon in world space, given a `Fixture fixture`, do this:

```
var shape = fixture.Shape as PolygonShape;
Transform transform;
fixture.Body.GetTransform(out transform);

foreach(Vector2 vertex in shape.Vertices)
{
    Vector2 theTransformedVertex = MathUtils.Multiply(ref transform, vertex);
}
```

You need these usings from Farseer, for the above code to work:

```
using FarseerPhysics.Collision.Shapes;
using FarseerPhysics.Common;
```

(This code written against Farseer 3.3.1)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Andrew! Very nice explanation and the code also works very well :)